# How to make a binary black and white image of solid and not solid areas?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of forest from drone (I applied k-means on it with 2 classes) I want to now make a ground truth out of it, how can I now make the forest to be all in black and not forest to be all in white color?

Forest from above:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is it an algorithm question or a technical question? If it is an algorithm question, and you have a B/W image which you want to transfer into a binary image, look into Otsu's method

Comment: Hi, I have put the image, Otsu does not work , check the image please , I want to make the spotty part of image ( in this case forest and tree to a one solid continues image) I do not know how to do it

Comment: Try your luck with deep learning or texture segmentation techniques. What you are asking is very challenging.

Comment: "the spotty part of the image" the whole image looks mostly spotty to me. what do you mean?

Comment: @PaulH I think the top-left quadrant is largely smooth in texture because it's grass. The remaining tree-covered parts are probably considered *"spotty"*. I may well be wrong!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need binary mask forest/no-forest.

Below is an empirical approach in which you need to select the hyperparameters manually.

I have relied on the fact that the forest has a gradient, unlike grass.

First, I filter small objects on grass with the median filter. Then I calculate second derivative to detect forest gradient (Laplacian filter). To fill the areas with no gradient (grass) I use the morphological operation "[closing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)" several times. Than I choose the threshold for an image to choose only "no-forest" regions, and place that mask in the red channel of the original image.

Results are here (binary mask is `image_closed_thresh`:

```
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\path_to_your_image\image.png")
image = image[15:-40,50:-10,:] # deleting axes from image

#Hyperparameters:
kernel_size_blur = 7 
kernel_size_derivative = 7
kernel_size_morph = (6,6)
threshold_morph = 800
iterations = 2

image_blur = cv2.medianBlur(image,kernel_size_blur)

image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # preprocessing for Laplacian filtering
image_lapl = cv2.Laplacian(image_gray, cv2.CV_16S, ksize=kernel_size_derivative)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernel_size_morph)
image_closed = cv2.morphologyEx(image_d, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=iterations)
_, image_closed_thresh = cv2.threshold(image_closed, 
                                  threshold_morph,
                                  250,
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 

image_fin = image.copy()
image_fin[:, :, 0] = image_closed_thresh # put the mask in the red channel

titles = ['Original image',
          'Blurred image (median filter)',
          'Laplacian image',
          'Closed image',
          'Closed image thresh',
          'Image with mask']

images = [image, image_blur, image_lapl, image_closed, image_closed_thresh, image_fin]

plt.figure (figsize = (10,15))

for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(3,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: results]